# Pass A File Through Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script called head.sh, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    read line1
    read line2
    read line3
}
echo $line1
echo $line2
echo $line3
```

And I need to call it like this:

```
sh head.sh < rhymes.txt
```

when I hardcode the filename in it works, but I can't work out how to pass in the file.

Comment: Are you reinventing utility "head"? Have you tried 'head -n 3' instead?

Comment: have you tried debugging your script ? read linex waits for your input. What behavior you expect ?

Comment: I'm trying to do this without head thus the complication. Haven't tried debugging. I just want it to operate on whatever file I pass through!

Comment: There was wrong direction `>`, now you changed to `<` and it must work now.

Comment: You've written what claims to be a `bash` shell script (see its first line) but you're running it with `sh`. On some systems this may be a completely different shell. Use `bash head.sh < rhymes.txt` to run it.

Comment: You should also quote your variables when you use them. (Not always essential but good practice. And avoids surprises.) For example `echo "$line1"`

Comment: You say “this is a very simple question.”   You’re wrong; it’s not a question at all.   What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your script like this and it works:

```
cat some_file | sh ./head.sh > rhymes.txt
```

Or you're not allowed to use pipe in your excercise?

EDIT: OK, however still, your script works for me:

```
$ cat test
11111111
22222222
33333333
4444
555
66
7
$ sh ./head.sh < test
11111111
22222222
33333333
$ cat ./head.sh 
#!/bin/bash
{
    read line1
    read line2
    read line3
}
echo $line1
echo $line2
echo $line3
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The file `rhymes.txt` contains the text which I want to pass through `head.sh`!

Comment: Edited above to reflect this

Comment: I've updated the post according to your comment.